# Georeferencing Raster automatically fails

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, wms, arcgis-10.3, georeferencing

While trying to auto register a raster image in georeferencing - using a wms raster layer as reference - I get the simple error message "Failed to auto register". Thereby the Link Table remains empty. I am currently using ArcGIS Desktop 10.3.1 and followed all the steps in the related ESRI Article (up to #7). The WMS Layer is projected in WGS84, data frame rotation is set to zero.

Comment: Fred,
Did you load the WMS Layer to ArcMap first? It sounded like you may have two different projection within ArcMap. So, I would clear that up in ArcMap and then bring the WMS Layer first then add other layers. I would also check the Layers at the TOC (Table of Contents) and right click on it and click on the tab on Coordinate Systems to check which projection ArcMap uses.
Can you explain to us what you were trying to do?

Comment: Hi Probert, basically I am trying to use a certain part of this WMS in order to georeference a corresponding layer. First I export the visible area by "File->Export Map". Then I drag the new png (or tiff, jpg etc.) onto the Data Frame with the WMS in it. The match of both is perfect, but the exported raster image lacks the spatial reference. The main reason for me trying to georeference my raster that way, is the slow server of my workplace, which takes forever to load single raster images of the WMS (which we use for georeferencing)...

Comment: On the other hand, I am wondering whether it is by any means possible to export raster images WITH a spatial reference from a WMS. That would solve the problem as well. Oh, I forgot: Both the WMS and exported the raster logically end up having the same projection - at least theoretically.

Comment: Is it a small area or a large area you are trying to georeference it ?

Comment: Hmm, tough to say...it differs, depending on the extent of the data that has to be georeferenced with the WMS-Rasters. If I wouldn't have to choose between the two, I would say "normal area" ;-). But more often than not, it is rather small than large. What strikes me as strange, is that the auto register fails despite the exported png matching the corresping part of the WMS perfectly. Basically I thought that errors occur more often when this is not the case and a change in rotation (e.g.) is required. Or, as you mentioned, the projections are different.

Comment: Because I asked, if you export small area it is much easier to deal with it than having the WMS as a whole  because the render is longer to re-draw and that could be why you are getting the errors.

Comment: Ah, I see. The exported areas a not that large, I would say then. With the parameters set correctly, they look really nice and sharp, which makes them ideal for georeferencing other fc or shape files. Just too bad they lack the projection of the WMS...

Comment: Well, WMS is a map services that ESRI put up as a reference.